# Kill process that doesn't show up in task manager

Tags: task-manager

I am able to kill running processes which show up in the task manager but there are some games like KnightOnline and Metin2 that don't show up in task manager and so I can't kill them. I've been searcing for a solution but couldn't find. This is an internet cafe software and I just want to close all programs and games when a customer leaves so that the new customer will have a fresh desktop.

As windows automaticly closes everything, I thought of ending the session and reloging but that doesn't seem to be easy and not the best way.

Waiting for your valuable comments

Comment: also related: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/76100/4780

Answer (score 13):

Use ProcessExplorer - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653 to check all processes and close what you want. It should show you every application on every account -if you have administrator rights of course.

To kill it programatically check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642231/how-to-kill-a-c-process

When you don't know name of process, but you know name of executable that is run on your computer ( C:...\Metin.exe) then you can iterate through all processes and search for process that in list of loaded modules (Modules property) has module with name of your executable (FileName property in ProcessModule class) . Maybe it helps.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for a way to do it by code

Comment: So describe your needs in question...

Comment: my question was "Kill process that doesn't show up in task manager" What's wrong with it? It already explains

Comment: "Hi, I am able to kill running processes which show up in the task manager but there are some games like KnightOnline and Metin2 that don't show up in task manager and so I can't kill them" - doeas it tell us that you want to kill it by code? It only describe that you have problems with task manager.

Comment: okay sorry, as I mentioned that it was an internet cafe software and put the c#4 tag below, I thought you could undestand that it was a programming question

Comment: ok, use Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses(); (from system.diagnostics) and call Kill() on process that you want to close.

Comment: That's the point! The games I want to kill aren't show up in task manager and in Processes. Is there a way to kill hidden processes? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find your application in the Applications tab then in the Task Manager switch to the second tab "Processes" find your desired application process then press "End Process", normally all processes have names similar to their applications, see the image below:

[image: Steps]

Comment: He's talking about hidden processes, which means they can't be found there.

Answer (score 2):

From a command line do

```
"tasklist | more"
```

pay attention to the PID (for instance 123)

to kill the item do

```
"taskkill /f /pid 123"
```

The benefit is that these commands also work on remote systems.

```
"tasklist /s <systemname> /u <domain>\<user>"
```

same for taskkill

Comment: He's talking about hidden processes, which means they can't be found there.

Comment: Was using Visual Studio to debug my application when it crashed.  Fixed the bug and tried to rebuild, but it couldn't complete because the application was still in use.  However, the application did not show up in Task Manager.  Tried restarting Visual Studio, but that didn't work either.  Visual Studio reported the PID, so I was able to kill the process via taskkill.  Just be sure to run the Command Prompt as an administrator.

Comment: @MattDavis I have run into a similar situation as well -- in my case the process started using System.Diagnostics.Process is not terminated. However I do notice that if I close task manager and reopen, that process is shown in the list.

Answer (score 1):

There is `Kill` method in `Process`. You may use it in such way:

```
var procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses(); // Get all processes in the system
procs[0].Kill();
```

There is also GetProcessesByName method with help of wich you can obtain pricesses by their names:

```
var procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox");
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't help me with hidden processes

Comment: Are you sure that your processes is really hidden? Is it true that processes isnt visible even if you press "Show processes from all users"? It also may be that KnightOnline and Metin2 have process names different from their program names