# Is it possible for a process to not appear in the Task Manager in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, process, task-manager

I was just wondering if it was possible for malware to hide itself in this way.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/268232/kill-process-that-doesnt-show-up-in-task-manager?rq=1

Comment: http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/23880-dkom-process-hider/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible for malware to hide itself from view to the OS itself, via a number of mechanisms, including filtering the output from the API calls that show processes in Task Manager.

This class of malware is usually called a [rootkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit), and is designed primarily to allow an adversary to keep access to a system long-term (called an advanced persistent threat, or APT) by hiding their actions and allowing the adversary to recover access if (partially) discovered. They act as a platform for further attacks on the system like installing keyloggers, spyware, sabotaging system software, or whatever else tickles the attackers fancy.

Rootkits must operate at a very low level in the OS architecture in order to do what they do, so malignant drivers and maliciously patched kernel libraries are generally involved in the better ones.